# Python doesn't think file exists when it does

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this function in my code:

```
def send_info(self, bfile, output_file_name, tag):
    self.command = r"sshpass -p {3} scp -P 5622 {0} {1}@{2}:/home/blender/Documents/blade_queue/".format(str(current_render.blend), self.uname, self.host, self.password)
    print self.command
    self.response = subprocess.check_output(self.command)
```

Which prints out:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD scp -P PORT /mnt/c/Users/Joseph\ Farah/Documents/python/cross_computer_rendering_gui/src/test.blend blender@IP /home/blender/Documents/blade_queue/
```

When I copy and paste this command into my shell, it works absolutely beautifully. However, trying to run this in Python results in:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

On that line.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add `shell=True` to the command. Does anyone know if this will cause any security vulnerabilities?

Edited command:

```
self.response = subprocess.check_output(self.command, shell=True)
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html): 17.5.2. Security Considerations
Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via shell=True, it is the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: For an example of what could go wrong: imagine the user setting their password to `; rm -rf / ;`...

Comment: You want to pass the arguments as a `list` that's explicitly split at the argument boundaries so you can avoid `shell=True`.  If the command is `["sshpass", '-p', self.password, 'scp', '-P', '5622',  str(current_render.blend), '{}@{}:/home/blender/Documents/blade_queue/'.format(self.uname, self.host)]` so all the arguments are explicitly passed independently, it would be both faster and more secure.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Hey Ned! I actually was working on this problem Tuesday night at Boston Python :) Thanks for the link!